# Need to replace EXACT strings in an array

Tags: php, arrays, replace

I have posted a similar issue like this before but this is getting me crazy because I cannot find the solution.

So let me explain. I scrape some values from a site in an array like this:

```
$Array1= Array (
        "UK 1.5", 
        "UK 01", 
        "UK 02", 
        "UK 03",
        "UK 03.5",
        "UK 04", 
        "UK 04.5", 
        "UK 05",
        "UK 05.5", 
        "UK 06", 
        "UK 06.5",
        "10 12 YRS",
        "12 13 YRS",
        "13 15 YRS"
);
```

And this array with KEYS and VALUES for what I search and what I replace with:

```
  $marGeneral = Array(
        'SELECT SIZE' => '',
        "09 10 YRS" => "9-10 ANI", 
        "11 12 YRS" => "11-12 ANI", 
        "13 14 YRS" => "13-14 ANI", 
        "15 16 YRS" => "15-16 ANI",
        'WAIST' => 'TALIE',
        'YRS'   => 'ANI',
        "UK 1.5" => "34", 
        "UK 01" => "32", 
        "UK 02" => "33", 
        "UK 03" => "35",
        "UK 03.5" => "36",
        "UK 04" => "36.5", 
        "UK 04.5" => "37", 
        "UK 05" => "38", 
        "UK 05.5" => "38.5", 
        "UK 06" => "39", 
        "UK 06.5" => "40", 
        "UK 07" => "40.5", 
        "UK 07.5" => "41",
        "UK 08" => "42", 
        "UK 08.5" => "42.5",
        "06" => "XS",
        "08" => "S",
        "10" => "M",
        "12" => "L",
        "14" => "XL" );
```

My concern is how do I replace the values without a conflict, for example if the scraper returns in the array value `12 13 YRS` , which is not defined as key in my search? Because in this case `(IF I TRY TO REPLACE ARRAY VALUES)` it returns me value `L 13 YRS` instead of `12 13 YRS` , because `12` is already another value to convert, but only when it is alone, and not in a string. If it is not defined, it should not interfere unless it is the only numeric value `12`.

I tried with `preg_replace()` , `str_replace()`, `strtr()` but no luck.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is impossible unless the string has some start/end of size. You need to define some rules on how to read the string. Give us a problem string to work with and how you want it to read the text. Preferably as close to what it looks like in real

Comment: What is supposed to happen with `12 13 YRS`? `12 13 ANI`?

Comment: `12 13 YRS` will become `12 13 ANI` if it is defined but some of the results may not be defined and in that case the search replaces the numeric values in these strings, a fact that I don't want

Comment: I understand that. But we need to know what the strings look like. It can probably be done but I need to know what a typical string looks like and what a problem string looks like (that is still possible)

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're probably putting `$marGeneral` inside your replacement function. As long as `$key` is the replacement string search and `$value` is the replacement, you will get this "error".

Try this:

```
array_walk(
    $Array1,
    function (&$size) use ($marGeneral) {
        if (array_key_exists($size, $marGeneral)) {
            $size = $marGeneral[$size];
        }
    }
);
```

I recommend you to do that within your database, but there it is.

Answer (score 0):

We might want to do an exact match instead of partial string replace. Here is my verbose solution:

```
foreach ($Array1 as &$value) {
  if (isset($marGeneral[$value])) {
    $value = $marGeneral[$value];
  }
}
unset($value);
```

If we want to be case insensitive, we might need to change all words to upper or lower cases before the loop.

Comment: array_key_exists() is much slower than isset(). And here, there is no difference.